# How to update an array on firebase using the onDisconnectUpdateChildValues

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, connection, database-connection

I want to remove the user from an array of users once they disconnect (real time firebase).

For example: John crashed, so remove johns node and reorder the indices. Please check image.

[image]

```
let connectedRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")
    
    connectedRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        
        guard let connected = snapshot.value as? Bool, connected else {
            completion(false)
            return
        }
        
        self.database.child("\(groupChatId)_F/users").onDisconnectUpdateChildValues([ ??? ]){ (error, ref) in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error)")
            }
            completion(true)
        }
    })
```

I am not entirely sure if it's even possible to do such a thing. If my intuition is true then please provide suggestions on how a problem can be overcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: arrays like the one you're using here are an anti-pattern in Firebase. I highly recommend reading [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

But aside from that: to update on disconnect you need to specify two things:

1. The exact, complete path that you want to write to.
2. The exact value that you want to write to that path.

Say you want to remove a value/path at `users/2` I'd recommend using:

```
self.database.child("\(groupChatId)_F/users/2").onDisconnectRemoveValue(){ (error, ref) in
  ...
```

This does mean that you need to know the path of the user (`2` in this example code). If you don't currently know that path, you have two main options:

- either to remember it in your code when you create the child node. So when you add `"Bob"`, remember in your code that you added him in node `2`.
- or you can make the path idempotent. For example, if you user names are unique, I'd recommend storing them in a structure like this:

  ```
  "users": {
    "Alex": true,
    "Bob": true,
    "John": true
  }
  ```